# Spark Tuning: How to parallelize more?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a big dataframe that is breaking down with code 137 (oom issues). My cluster already has the max memory I can give per executor, etc.

My basic workflow is:

1. Do initial set of operations
2. With those running normally, `df.checkpoint()`
3. Run next operation
4. Try to display / execute the DAG -- fail

I have tried to change the number of blocks:

```
df = df.repartition(1000)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)
```

But I cannot get the blocks in the image below to change from 2000 (conceivably they need to increase to solve OOM).

What else can I try to get past this stage? (getting a bigger machine is not a solution).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIUXO.png

Comment: What is your AQE setting?

Comment: AQE is enabled.

Comment: Try with it turned off.

Comment: Spark Structured Streaming allows splitting big load into smaller chunks. Though, if you run aggregation (or similar operations) on whole dataset then streaming could be tricky.